# Don't find folder in regedit for setting SQLSecurityCheck

Tags: sql-server, ms-word, office365, regedit

I want to use Merge using Office Home Business 2016.
I have to set the SQLSecuritycheck property but I can't find the way.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Options
```

I find the path only up to

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft
```

There is no Office folder.
I tried to manually create the Office folder and the other subfolders but it doesn't work.
Where should I set the SQLSecurityCheck with this version of Office?

Comment: Do note that the **...\Software\Microsoft Office\** is NOT the same as the **...\Software\Microsoft\Office\** key.

Comment: Remember, please that Stack Overflow is for *programming questions*. This appears to be an end-user issue so is more appropriate for a venue such as Super User. It's off-topic, here.